Are there Rabbinical commentaries on the symbolism of the altar fire revived by Nehemiah?
I gather that 2 Maccabees is outside the canon, but surely Rabbinical commentators were aware of it. With the goal of parsing out some of the symbolism seen in the following verses 1:23-28 (alternative version on Sefaria):

For when our ancestors were being led captive to Persia, the pious
priests of that time took some of the fire of the altar and secretly
hid it in the hollow of a dry cistern, where they took such
precautions that the place was unknown to anyone. 20 But after many
years had passed, when it pleased God, Nehemiah, having been
commissioned by the king of Persia, sent the descendants of the
priests who had hidden the fire to get it. And when they reported to
us that they had not found fire but only a thick liquid, he ordered
them to dip it out and bring it. 21 When the materials for the
sacrifices were presented, Nehemiah ordered the priests to sprinkle
the liquid on the wood and on the things laid upon it. 22 When this
had been done and some time had passed, and when the sun, which had
been clouded over, shone out, a great fire blazed up, so that all
marveled.

Is it possible to gloss that the preservation and transference of the altar fire from the First Temple to the Second holds a symbolic meaning? In Iranian traditions, such a symbol might be thought of as khvarenah, often glossed as "glory" and denoting divine sponsorship (though typically of a king).
Question
Are there any Midrashic traditions or even kabbalistic exegeses on the altar fire mentioned in 2 Maccabees? 

Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Re "surely Rabbinical commentators were aware of it" - it's unclear which apocryphal works were known to the Talmudic sages. Even in the Middle Ages when Jews became more familiar with such works, the most popular Jewish account of Hanukkah, the Maccabees and related topics was the Scroll of Antiochus, which is considerably shorter than 1 and 2 Maccabees and doesn't include this story. In other words, it's not so certain that there are rabbinical sources out there that refer to this.

@Harel13 I see, helpful, thanks! Will note for the future.
